# Error detection in shell script commands such as "make"

Tags: bash, shell, error-handling, makefile

I want to write a script to **extract**, **configure**, **make** and **make install** a source(xyz.tar.bz2). But I want to stop this script if there is an error in one of these commands. Is there any signal or method specially for **make** command to detect errors during execution to stop script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's true; the more simple way is below...

```sh
tar xvf foo.tar.bz2 && make && make install
```

Answer (score 2):

Make normally aborts if any command it runs returns a non-zero exit code (including being killed by a signal). So you just need to make sure your script exists (with an error) if a command fails. Also, make itself then exists with a non-zero status (so you can detect `make` or `make install` failing). Note that make can be told to ignore errors on a per-command basis (by prefixing the command with a `-`), but this isn't the default.

You can do this in two main ways:

1. `set -e` (though beware that [`set -e` has a lot of problems](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/105))
2. Test each command for failure (e.g., `tar xzf foo.tar.gz || exit 1`)

Alternatively, you can use `make` the way it is intended, and write make rules to do all these steps.